# Ruby koan 280 - where is the reference to to_str?

Tags: ruby

I've had a look around and can't find this question:
For ruby koan 280 it's telling me the following underscore section should be false:

```
  def test_to_str_allows_objects_to_be_treated_as_strings
    assert_equal __, File.exist?(CanBeTreatedAsString.new) # test passes, if __ is changed to false
  end
```

OK, fine. But how does this test that `to_str` allows objects to be treated as Strings? Here is the CanBeTreatedAsString class, which DOES include a `to_str` method:

```
  class CanBeTreatedAsString
    def to_s
      "string-like"
    end

    def to_str
      to_s
    end
  end
```

...but how is that relevant to the assert_equal code above? Is it that `.exist?` expects a String? 
This page:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F
says the parameter can be an IO object. Are some methods specific about the parameter types they receive? And if so, how do I tell?

Answer (score 0):

`File.exist?` takes a string or an IO. Part of how it does that is by calling `to_str` on the object. A string returns itself for `to_str`. Otherwise, it's only supposed to be implemented on objects that can be used as a string.

Due to Ruby's duck typing conventions, there isn't an easy way to tell. However, usually, if a method accepts a string, then it will call `String.try_convert` (which uses `to_str`) to allow duck typing. In a similar fashion, many objects that expect an int call `Integer.try_convert` (which calls `to_int`) to convert the argument.

Here's more information on the various conversion protocols: http://pivotallabs.com/messages-not-types-exploring-rubys-conversion-protocols/

EDIT: Forgot to add the how can you tell